# impala split_part function not accepting negative indexing

Tags: sql, impala, hue

I'm trying to access the second to last element in a split_part function. as I saw you should be able to use a negative index to look right to left.
In impala however is get a "invalid field position" error

```
SELECT split_part(string1;string2;string3;string4, ";", -2)
```

```
SELECT split_part(string3;string4, ";", -2)
```

```
SELECT split_part(string2;string3;string4, ";", -2)
```

I was hoping to get "string3" returned for all the above examples.
Any help on how to do this in Impala would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that argument must be >=1. So you can use below workaround - you calculate position of last but one string and then use split part accordingly.
You can use below code.

```
SELECT split_part(stc_column, ';', length(stc_column)-length(replace(stc_column,';','')))
```

Here is output for your input scenario -

```
SELECT split_part('string2;string3;string4', ';', length('string2;string3;string4') - length(replace('string2;string3;string4',';',''))  
)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, cheers I ended up using : REVERSE(split_part(REVERSE("string1;string2;string3;string4"), ";", 2)) but both work for what I wanted cheers